Absurdo de votos negativos
Entiendo que el sitio tenga la mecánica de votos y que en teoría para la estadística del sitio y para el mercado del sitio funcione...
Pero estoy seguro que para algunos usuarios no nos sirve ...

8 Votos negativos en un solo día... 16 puntos de reputación perdidos... para aquellos que tengan miles será moco de pavo caído... pero para otros que invertimos horas en dar una buena respuesta no le vemos el sentido...
Y esto solo es lo del día de hoy, durante la última semana alguien ha estado creando cuenta y metiendo votos negativos apenas tiene la oportunidad a diestra y siniestra... asumo esto ya que la coincidencia de que dos cuentas emitan votos negativos en preguntas/respuesta relativamente VIEJAS dudo que sea una coincidencia...
Los usuarios necesitamos una nueva mecánica de voto o una mecánica eficiente para evitar esto o que simplemente nos digan que nos larguemos del sitio.
¿Quién protege que esto no ocurra o quien se hace responsable de esto?
Actualizacion del 28/06/2024:
Seguimos con más votos en serie:

Decir que esta Sucediendo tambien es mal visto ahora por la moderacion del sitio:

Resultado:


¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? ¿Qué es el voto serial y cómo me afecta?

@RyanM no, eso no responde a mi pregunta, por que crees que lo haria? verifica el contexto es diferente por que hay multiples cuentas involucradas y no una sola cuenta (tal como lo dije en el post).

Los votos en su captura de pantalla ocurrieron hace cerca una hora (como se puede ver en su página de Reputación). Tiene que esperar 24 horas, como dice esa pregunta.

@RyanM Esa captura es de hace 2 semanas... 8 Votos negativos en un solo día (No son de hoy) esto quiere decir que ya... ha pasado más de 24 horas y no se ha hecho esa reversión…

"Esa captura es de hace 2 semanas" Claramente eso no es cierto. Si eso es cierto, ¿en qué fecha ocurrieron esos votos?  Una vez más, sólo hay que mirar su página de reputación para ver cuándo fue: hoy.

@RyanM Venimos reportando los votos negativos desde hace casi 1 año... y en mi caso se acentuaron la últimas dos semanas... y si hoy he recibido votos negativos también pero no tantos como la semana pasada... solo te puedo decir que es nefasto lo que hacen los usuario en esta comunidad y que los en teoría encargados no les interese ese comportamiento... a pesar de que está claro que están bypaseando las mecánicas del sistema de reversado de votos...

@RyanM Si das el tiempo a lo mejor los otros usuarios afectados que seran pocos obviamente lo confirmaran ...

el compañero viene reportando este tema tiempo atras y es del  diario, no es justo que uno se gaste horas de su vida en ayudar a los demas y haci mejorar el sitio que fue para lo que se creo. Y que vengan unas personas a tirarte tu trabajo nomas por que si. Y no solo lo afecta a el tambien a los demas!.

Es lamentable que ocurra cosas como estas, entiendo tu frustración ya que estás en un grado de indefensión total, hay mucha maldad y ganas de joder y verte molesto detrás de esos votos negativos

Voy a aclarar un punto: Hace algún tiempo (cuando el sitio tenía más movimiento), varios usuarios advertimos un problema con los votos negativos, el foco era hacia los usuarios nuevos, por lo menos esa era mi preocupación y me consta que lo era de algún otro, el asunto no pasaba por votos hacia usuarios con alta reputación, porque por lo menos desde mi visión eso no genera problemas. Señalo esto, porque hay un comentario que hace alusión a esto, y no quiero que se mesclen las temas

Es que el contexto no es sobre el target de los votos negativos ... si no el hecho de que sean dos cuentas simultaneas bypaseando el roleback de votos ... por eso la pregunta es quien se encarga de proteger a los usuarios de esto o quien se hace responsable de esto ... aparte de la apreciacion personal y las faltas de respeto en los comentarios del chat y la ultima respuesta que dieron aqui ...

Llevo 1 año y 10 meses en el sitio, he emitido 59 votos en contra, muchos de estos votos son ahora último que para votar para eliminar respuesta he tenido que votar negativamente. En casi el mismo periodo de tiempo, este usuario ha emitido 556 votos en contra. ¿Los votos que él emite son válidos, pero los que le emiten a él no?

No sé si son 2 cuentas, pudo haber sido un voto en la pregunta y otra en la respuesta. De todas maneras, ya dije lo que quería decir. Por lo que no responderé más comentarios

@Yussef los votos deben tener una logica/objetivo en el sitio... y es valorar las preguntas y respuesta ... no al usuario ... no es lo mismo emitir 8 votos seguidos sin evaluar nada a alguien por que te cae mal ... a emitir votos evaluando el contenido ... no es de quien sea validos los votos ... es el correcto uso de la herramienta ...

Esta situación es curiosa porque hice un comentario en una respuesta de un  usuario y, de manera ingenua, inicié una discusión en una pregunta que hizo en Meta. Sorprendentemente, recibí más votos negativos en tres días de los que había recibido en un año. Sin embargo, esos votos negativos no me afectan mucho, ya que mi objetivo principal al responder es que el buscador de Google lleve a las personas a una respuesta útil, independientemente de si es aceptada o si recibe votos positivos.

@clay no comprendo tu comentario ... a ver ... dices que tu objetivo es ayudar a alguien aunque las personas que esten viendote ayudar te traten mal? y que eso no te afecta ... aunque eso no tiene nada que ver con este post en donde trato de desmostrar el uso doble de cuentas para bypasear una mecanica del sitio ...

chatgpt has un analisis logico de la frase "
Esta situación es curiosa porque hice un comentario en una respuesta de un usuario y, de manera ingenua, inicié una discusión en una pregunta que hizo en Meta. Sorprendentemente, recibí más votos negativos en tres días de los que había recibido en un año. Sin embargo, esos votos negativos no me afectan mucho, ya que mi objetivo principal al responder es que el buscador de Google lleve a las personas a una respuesta útil, independientemente de si es aceptada o si recibe votos positivos."

chatgpt: Premisa 5: "...independientemente de si es aceptada o si recibe votos positivos."
Esta premisa especifica las condiciones bajo las cuales el hablante considera exitosa su participación, desvinculándola de la validación social directa.


Resulta que hay una conspiración contra tí con una mano negra que te pone votos negativos... (todo esto sin tener evidencias, nada más que sospechas) ¿No será más sencillo que tus respuestas son malas y por eso la gente te las vota negativo? Eso no se te había ocurrido, ¿a qué no?

"Seguimos con más votos en serie:" ...todos los cuales se han revertido automáticamente al poco tiempo, al igual que los primeros. Sólo tienes que esperar, como te han dicho repetidamente.

@ordago no me sorprendería que algunos usuarios hayan votado negativo a Arkanis debido a que algunos (o pocos) miembros lo han juzgado por sus publicaciones aquí. Sin embargo, una vez yo también recibí votos negativos "por que si", así que si hay posibilidad de que haya algo raro.

Yo creo que si hay una mala intención de algunos usuarios, sobre todo viejos, de calificar negativamente las respuestas. He observado, además, de que ese tipo de comportamiento tóxico se da en mayor medida en la etiqueta de PHP, donde me da miedo responder, y algo menor en Javascript. Por otro lado, puede ser que el compañero no sea del agrado de algunos, pero esa no es razón suficiente para descalificar su actividad, si no lo amerita. Ojalá nunca lleguen a tener un puesto de poder en una compañía y mucho menos en un gobierno.

Ahora que lo pienso, que pasó con la sala de chat destinada a hablar sobre votos negativos?

Arkanis, espero no estés hablando más de una vez al mes sobre el tema. Si no, te seré sincero, también borraría tus chats, ya que generaría mucha negatividad. Más allá de que lo dicho sea cierto o no.

@DanteS. por eso lo publique aquí... y seguiré quejándome del sistema de votos ... hasta que lo cambien o lo mejoren ... no me importa si a 4  les parece mal que vaya a llorar a otro lado como me lo dicen ami ... pero este es el canal destinado para estos temas...

@aeportugal No creo que ningun veterano pierda el tiempo creando multicuentas y yendo a "cazar" a una persona, por los motivos que sea, aun más sabiendo que existe la revocación de puntos en votos seriales y demás en la plataforma (lo cual, responde a esta pregunta y se ha demostrado que funciona, solo hace falta ver el perfil del usuario). Son suficientemente maduros y conscientes de lo que hay como para no perder el tiempo en estas "chiquilladas". Eso no quiere decir que no pueda haber alguna excepción, que siempre las hay, pero reitero, es una perdida innecesaria de tiempo si lo hacen asi

@FranciscoIALover a mi no me cansa, como te he manifestado, me interesan los debates. Pero pinta a que la mayoría (que pueden ser más que 4) si está cansada. No digo que no te quejes, pero que estaría bueno que evites insistir mucho al respecto. Y aunque si este es el lugar adecuado, no se apoyan preguntas "duplicadas".

Lamento que te ocurra esto, a ti o a cualquiera. Felizmente el sistema de reversión de voto serial está para estos casos y la puntuación perdida será recuperada al cabo de un tiempo establecido (como mínimo 24 horas).
Sin embargo, noto que tu pregunta / queja, contiene una petición que has realizado de diferentes formas y por diferentes medios:

Los usuarios necesitamos una nueva mecánica de voto o una mecánica eficiente para evitar esto o que simplemente nos digan que nos larguemos del sitio.

Esta petición debes hacerla en Meta del sitio en inglés, porque estás pidiendo un cambio del sistema de votos que afecta a toda la red.
Ahora, cualquier usuario con tiempo y con conocimiento del sitio y de la historia detrás del mismo, sabe que el sistema de votos y reputación son la base de todo. Por lo que tu petición, así como la de muchos antes que tú, estará destinada a no ser tomada en cuenta.
Piensa que es intentar cambiar las reglas del Poker en cada Casino ya establecido, o cambiar la esencia teológica de una religión establecida hace miles de años.
Ahora, el escandaloso voto en serie que estás sufriendo desde 2 cuentas, según tus palabras:

... asumo esto ya que la coincidencia de que dos cuentas emitan votos negativos en preguntas/respuesta relativamente VIEJAS dudo que sea una coincidencia...

me lleva a cuestionarme cómo llegaste tan rápido a esa conclusión, y a quién le has presentado esas pruebas que lo corroboran. No pido que lo hagas aquí, sino por medio de los canales apropiados.
Incluso, esta misma pregunta / queja debió exponerse primero en los canales adecuados y no ventilarla públicamente aquí. Y no lo digo porque esto me moleste o me cause incomodidad a mi. Lo digo porque en mi poca experiencia, exponerte de esta forma tan repetidas veces, incluyendo todo lo discutido desde hace tanto tiempo en el chat, hace que seas vulnerable a este tipo de ataques y te pones tú mismo una diana de tiro al blanco.
El hecho de que muchos de los que participamos en esta comunidad somos profesionales, no implica que todos actuemos de esa forma. Yo mismo he caido algunas veces en discusiones banales y he satirizado mucha de la verborrea que a veces se expone aqui o en el chat.
Por último, ante tu pregunta:

¿Quién protege que esto no ocurra o quien se hace responsable de esto?

La respuesta es simple:
Tú te protejes a ti mismo, al no entrar en el constante y ya cansino repetir y actuar en Meta y en el chat con el tema del cambio en el sistema de votos.
Tú eres responsable de tu propia exposición al no aceptar que tu propuesta no es recibida positivamente. Eres responsable de cuidar tu imagen como usuario de esta comunidad. Eres tan responsable como quien te haya puesto los votos de forma serial. Diría que más responsable incluso, porque tu eterna discordancia con el sitio ha llevado a que alguien quiera hacerte sentir lo que sientes ahora, y por lo visto, le sigues dando gusto a esa persona o grupo de personas, mientras sigas exponiéndote de esta manera.
¿Cómo deberías actuar? Siempre con respeto por delante, y aportando postivamente tanto en tus respuestas como en tus comentarios y participación en todo el sitio.
Tal como te lo han dicho en reiteradas ocasiones: si no estás dispuesto a aceptar el sistema de votos y reputación, nadie te obliga a participar en el sitio. No hay nada de malo en participar o dejar de hacerlo, no hay pérdidas, tu esfuerzo seguirá allí después que dejes de participar. Tal vez sólo se vea afectado el ego y el orgullo personal, que podrían salir heridos, pero esto no sería culpa del sitio.

gracias por tu respuesta y parece ser la única persona cuerente en la comunidad, pero quería aclara algo...

aquí no se ha atacado por mi parte a ningún usuario ni se ha ofendido a ninguno, la queja aquí es sobre el mal uso de la herramienta y sobre que mecanismos o quien pueda apoyarnos, buscamos simplemente eso... sin embargo otros usuarios que si son tóxicos se quejan de nosotros, como si buscaramos hacer algo mal... cuando lo único que intentamos es expresar nuestra inconformidad... y para colmo lo hacen con palabras soeces y agrediendonos...

lo peor de todo es que mientras nosotros "nos quejamos" por que la cuchara este limpia... el otro grupo de sussodichos se quejan... por que nosotros nos quejamos... es como el bebe que llora por que el otro llora...

Dijiste lo que le quize decir a Arka desde el principio, pero nunca podía expresarlo bien. Gracias!

Es verdad que no atacaste a uno en especifico. Sin embargo, al hacer cosas como decirle "sinverguenzas" a la comunidad y sacando el tema a relucir cuando para la mayoría no se logra más que amargarnos todos, atacas y ofendes a los usuarios que buscan pensar positivo y se sienten identificados como aquellos "sinverguenzas".

@DanteS. el que se pica es por que ají come... te aseguro que si alguien usa bien la herramientas de votos... Este post le dará igual... y si le ha pasado antes, lo apoyara...

Estas discusiones son cansinas y nos creemos que reafirman el ego de quien las genera, entramos en controversias banales, sin sustancia, y perdemos el tiempo intentando convencer y mostrar sus errores y la actitud negativa de quien las produce, cuando éste no va a ser convencido, y no lo será nunca. Tiene TOC evidentemente, lo cual no es malo en sí, tengo amigos que lo sufren, pero son amigos, y los puedo y quiero soportar, y nos echamos unas risas siempre comentándolo.  En este caso, ha encontrado su via de escape aqui y mejor obviar lo que diga o será peor. Ni caso. Vive y deja vivir.

@FranciscoIALover insultar o criticar de forma pasivo-agresiva a un grupo de gente es una forma de ataque, las razones por las que se identifican con ese grupo o si se lo merecen es tema aparte.

@DanteS. creo que es peor cuando un grupo ataca a una sola persona usando mecánicas del sitio ...

Como bien te explicaba RyanM, el sistema detecta automáticamente los casos de voto serial y dado el caso, les revierte. Si miras a tu reputación ahora mismo aparece esto:

Los votos seriales que has recibido han sido corregidos por el sistema.

No eso lo hicieron de forma manual recientemente, a pesar de que digas que fue el sistema y que asi esta en el layout the sitio, si no me quejo no lo corrijen ... y el problema no es tanto los votos... si no la brecha de que cualquiera puede tener 2 cuentas y comenzar a emitir votos y no se le banea y eso si esta en contra de las politicas de usuario.

Que pereza da tu plan victimista, "Todos están en contra de mi, hay un complot para marginarme". Eres tu solo el que se pone en estas situaciones. He visto muchas ocasiones de votos seriales corregidos por el sistema, tardará 1 dia o incluso más en corregirlos, pero lo hace tanto si son negativos como positivos. Dejate ya de victimismos y de acusaciones sin ningún tipo de prueba porque lo unico que haces es especular de que las cosas funcionan de una manera sin tener pruebas de ello

las pruebas estan en el post, en los comentarios y las respuestas que dan ...

@FranciscoIALover tal vez sería buena idea mostrar esas pruebas en la publicación a traves de links o imagenes tal como hiciste con el chat.

@DanteS. busca la respuesta que dio aquí abajo  Moe... y dime si la respuesta cumple con el objetivo del sitio y las políticas de usuario... si hablamos de toxicidad... en el sitio... vamos en mala dirección...

@FranciscoIALover esta va a ser la ultima vez que te responda, porque no tiene sentido hablar con una pared. Ningun moderador tiene la potestad de revertir votos, puedes investigarlo en el meta general si estas interesado. Es el sistema el que revierte los votos seriales cuando les detecta. Si lo crees bien, si no...mala suerte. Desde luego debe ser triste creer que todo el mundo está en contra tuya, en mi caso te aseguro que tengo cosas mas importantes que hacer.

@FranciscoIALover y si borran esa respuesta? Además, reunir todas las pruebas en una sola publicación ayudará a que puedas mostrar de forma ordenada y sencilla para otros dichas pruebas. Ya he dejado un comentario y reporté la respuesta de Candid. Y si bien recibió un oleaje de positivos, también se contrarrestó con negativos. Mirá, gran parte de la "conspiración contra vos" te la estás ganando con tu forma de abordar el problema como te han dicho. Si, el sitio podría ser mejor, pero siento que en otros sitios, ya te hubieran funado y baneado permanentemente hace mucho.

el sitio nunca sera mejor de lo que en algun dia fue ... por suerte nadie es eterno ...
